# Query for output

Tags: sql

I was given this question in an interview. There are 2 tables `A` & `B` (they have only one column `id`) with the following data

```
Table A
id
--
1
2
3

Table B
id
--
2
3
4
```

I need to produce an output of following type:

```
id | Present
------------
1  | "In A"
2  | "In A & In B"
3  | "In A & In B"
4  | "In B"
```

I came with a solution using `Union` clause, like this:

```
SELECT id, "In A" FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B)
UNION
SELECT id, "In A & In B" WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM B)
UNION
SELET id, "In B" WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM A)
```

*In this case I am using 3 separate queries and using `UNION` to combine them. I think Interview was only looking for my approach & not the exact query. That being said, after I proposed my solution, he told me that there is atleast one solution which uses only 2 queries, and there also exist a solution which uses only 1 query. I tried using `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but could not come up with anything concrete.*

So what would be a better query to get the following output? Interviewer didn't mentioned any specific database, so I think a generic solution exist. But its ok if query is specific to some SQL flavour. Generic would be nice though.

Comment: Any particular flavour of SQL?

Comment: @Nick Interviewer didn't mention anything. I would want anything generic which would work across databases. But if that is not possible, something specific will also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an answer that's fairly DBMS agnostic (although it won't work on MySQL due to lack of support for `FULL OUTER JOIN`):

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.id, B.id) AS id,
       CASE WHEN A.id IS NULL THEN 'In B'
            WHEN B.id IS NULL THEN 'In A'
            ELSE 'In A & In B' END AS Present
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
```

Output:

```
id  present
1   In A
2   In A & In B
3   In A & In B
4   In B
```

The query relies on the fact that if there is no matching row in the second table of an outer join then a row with NULL values will be `JOIN`ed. So if `A.id IS NULL`, that means the value was only in table B. If `B.id IS NULL`, then the value was only in table A. And if both `id` values are non-NULL, the value must have been in both tables.

[Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b0a75fb94d208215d5e69c036299dc7)
[SQL Server demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8b9cfafd322f5f286ae1093f9eb8814)
[PostgreSQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c8b9cfafd322f5f286ae1093f9eb8814)

Comment: I could not come up with that on my own. Need to practice more it seems. :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `full outer join` for this!  It doesn't behave well with duplicates or `NULL` values.  I prefer `union` and aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when in_a = 1 and in_b = 1 then 'In A & In B'
             when in_a = 1 then 'In A'
             else 'In B'
        end) as present
from ((select id, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
       from a
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select id, 0, 1
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by id;
```

In a database that supports `concat_ws()`, I would simplify this to:

```
select id,
       concat_ws(' & ', in_a, in_b) as present
from ((select id, 'In A' as in_a, NULL as in_b
       from a
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select id, NULL, 'In B'
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by id;
```